# Could not resolve nested dictionary from XML via Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, xml, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have to resolve the following configuration from XML configuration file via Castle Windsor:

```
interface IMyConfiguration
{
    string Url { get; set; }
    string Token { get; set; }
    Dictionary <string, Dictionary <string, Guid>> Mapping { get; set; }
}
```

From XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <components>
        <component id="myConfiguration"
                   service="Application.IMyConfiguration, Application"
                   type="Application.MyConfiguration, Application">
            <parameters>
                <Url>example.com</Url>
                <Token>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Token>
                <Mapping>
                    <dictionary>
                        <entry key="AA">${mapping_one}</entry>
                        <entry key="BB">${mapping_two}</entry>
                    </dictionary>
                </Mapping>
            </parameters>
        </component>

        <component id="mapping_one"
                   service="System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Guid, mscorlib]]"
                   type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Guid, mscorlib]]">
            <parameters>
                <dictionary>
                    <dictionary>
                        <entry key="aa">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                        <entry key="bb">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                        <entry key="cc">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                    </dictionary>
                </dictionary>
            </parameters>
        </component>

        <component id="mapping_two"
                   service="System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Guid, mscorlib]]"
                   type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Guid, mscorlib]]">
            <parameters>
                <dictionary>
                    <dictionary>
                        <entry key="aa">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                        <entry key="bb">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                        <entry key="cc">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                    </dictionary>
                </dictionary>
            </parameters>
        </component>
    </components>
</configuration>
```

But what I get is `Mapping` property set to `null`. Other properties resolve properly.

What am I doing wrong? How to do it properly?

I tried to google the solution, but it seems that no one uses nested dictionaries for configuration :)

The best idea I've obtained so far is to use list instead of dictionary.

---

**UPD.** Resolving works fine if I put `mapping_one` and `mapping_two` inside the MyConfiguration component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <components>
        <component id="myConfiguration"
                   service="Application.IMyConfiguration, Application"
                   type="Application.MyConfiguration, Application">
            <parameters>
                <Url>example.com</Url>
                <Token>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Token>
                <Mapping>
                    <dictionary>
                        <entry key="AA">
                            <dictionary>
                                <entry key="aa">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                                <entry key="bb">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                                <entry key="cc">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                            </dictionary>
                        </entry>
                        <entry key="BB">
                            <dictionary>
                                <entry key="aa">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                                <entry key="bb">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                                <entry key="cc">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</entry>
                            </dictionary>
                        </entry>
                    </dictionary>
                </Mapping>
            </parameters>
        </component>
    </components>
</configuration>
```

But I want nested dictionaries to be separate components.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time at home using xml linq.  I don't have VS so I hope I get the syntax correct

```
XDocument doc = XDocument("filename");

List<MyConfiguration> configs = doc.Descendants("parameters").Select(x => new MyConfiguration() {
   Url = (string)x.Descendants("Url").FirstOrDefault(),
   Token = (string)x.Descendants("Token").FirstOrDefault(),
   Mapping = x.Elements("Mapping").Select(m => m.Element("dictionary").Elements("entry")
             .GroupBy(y => (string)y.Attribute("key"), z => z.Descendants("entry")
                .GroupBy(a => (string)a.Attribute("key"), b => (string)b)
                .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault))
             .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.FirstOrDefault())
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

The code assume a class

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. The problem is to resolve **nested** dictionary (e.g. `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Guid>>`) via [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/).

Comment: Your origanl posting wasn't consistent so I wasn't sure what you wanted.  You updated request is much better.  I updated the code.  Your xml has multiple levels with same tag name so you can't just use Descendants.